# minimum number of character deletions (of both) required to turn these strings into anagrams?

Tags: perl, hash

Two strings are given,how many minimum number of character deletions (of both) required to turn these strings into anagrams.
Constraint: Need to use single hash

aaabbc abc

Output - 3 ( 2 a and 1 b)

I was able to achieve this using two hashes and tried below solution using one hash -

```
my $str1 = 'aaabbc';
my $str2 = 'abc';

my %h;

map{$h{$_}++} sort(//,$str1);
map{$h{$_}++} sort(//,$str2);

my $c = 0;

foreach (keys(%h)) {
    if($h{$_} == 1) {
        $c++;
    }
}

print "$c\n";
```

It will fail in many case like ('xxx', 'yyy').
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that `map` would be better off written as a `for` loop. Chances are if you're not assigning the result of `map` you're using the wrong tool.

Comment: Is the deletion taking place in the beginning or the end or in the middle as well?

Comment: Also there is a syntax error in your code. You are missing a `;`. You should not write code in the question but actually copy and paste real code that you have tested.

Comment: Thanks simbabque, I have fixed the code and added semicolon.

Comment: Sobrique, Used map to count the characters. I Agree with your suggestions to use to for loop for the clarity though. Anything can you think of about the solution by using single hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a single hash (smells like homework) increment the count for characters in the first string and decrement it for characters in the second string. Equal numbers of the same character will cancel out. Any non-zero values that remain are the magnitude of the difference, so take the absolute value when tallying the total number of differences.

```
my $str1 = 'aaabbc';
my $str2 = 'abc';
my %h;
my $c;

$h{$_}++ foreach split //, $str1;
$h{$_}-- foreach split //, $str2;

$c += abs($_) foreach values %h;

print $c;
```

Comment: That will break if you do `fooo` and `bar`. In that case you need to check if the absolute is the same as the sum of the lengths.

Comment: Michael Carman, Thanks for your work but you smelled completely wrong.I had two solution to this problem but was trying this approach.I was not able to implement in third way so i asked for the suggestions.

Comment: @simbabque: You seem to have interpreted the question differently than I did. I read it as a sort of a Levenshtein edit distance that ignored order. Given that interpretation, I'd expect `fooo` and `bar` to yield 7, which this does. If my interpretation is wrong, hopefully @CodeQuestor will clarify.